# Change google maps polyline grid background color?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can create a grid using google maps polyline, now I'd like to change the color of a given cell, problem is I don't know how to select or define cells, how to iterate through them or maybe on click select a given cell.

Here is the code for creating grid lines with polyline:

http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8z38L0o0/1/

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<!-- Declare the div, make it take up the full document body -->
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 95%;"></div>
```

```
var map;

var qtrArray = [];
var linesArray = [];
var Startlatlng;
var llOffset = 0.0666666666666667;

var drawGridBox = false;
var gridline;
var polylinesquare;
var latPolylines = [];
var lngPolylines = [];
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.00, -100.00),
    zoom: 10,
    streetViewControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scaleControl: true
  });


  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    createGridLines(map.getBounds());
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


function createGridLines(bounds) {
  // remove any existing lines from the map
  for (var i = 0; i < latPolylines.length; i++) {
    latPolylines[i].setMap(null);
  }
  latPolylines = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < lngPolylines.length; i++) {
    lngPolylines[i].setMap(null);
  }
  lngPolylines = [];
  // don't add the lines if the boxes are too small to be useful
  if (map.getZoom() <= 6) return;
  var north = bounds.getNorthEast().lat();
  var east = bounds.getNorthEast().lng();
  var south = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();
  var west = bounds.getSouthWest().lng();

  // define the size of the grid
  var topLat = Math.ceil(north / llOffset) * llOffset;
  var rightLong = Math.ceil(east / llOffset) * llOffset;

  var bottomLat = Math.floor(south / llOffset) * llOffset;
  var leftLong = Math.floor(west / llOffset) * llOffset;

  for (var latitude = bottomLat; latitude <= topLat; latitude += llOffset) {
    // lines of latitude
    latPolylines.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: [
        new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, leftLong),
        new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, rightLong)
      ],
      map: map,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: '#0000FF',
      strokeOpacity: 0.5,
      strokeWeight: 1
    }));
  }
  for (var longitude = leftLong; longitude <= rightLong; longitude += llOffset) {
    // lines of longitude
    lngPolylines.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: [
        new google.maps.LatLng(topLat, longitude),
        new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLat, longitude)
      ],
      map: map,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: '#0000FF',
      strokeOpacity: 0.5,
      strokeWeight: 1
    }));
  }
}
```

How can I select grid cells and change color/hilight them?